# R, Multiply columns from different data frames and store new values as new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, df1 has stock symbols and values. df2 correlations with the same  names but arranged as rows.  df1 has many more columns than df2, but all columns that are in df2 exist in df1. I need to  multiply matching columns and store newly created values as a new dataframe. The new dataframe will only have a stock symbol and then all multiplications of df1*df2. 
The data looks like this:

df1

```
 A Company Symbol   Earn.GR MF  Effic MF
TRUE    1.320005832 -0.080712181
```

df2:

```
    Variable    Corr
1   Val MF  0.312140675
2   Earn.GR.withCorr MF 0.992410721
```

I have tried this code, but not getting the expected result:
Transpose df2:

```
df2 <- transpose (df2)
rownames(df2) <- colnames(df2)
```

Match and multiply columns

```
df3 <-  df1[names(df1) %in% names(df2)] <- sapply(names(df1[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]), 
                                            function(x) df1[[x]] * df2[[x]])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is there any code example you could provide showing us what you've done so far?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/7856717) for guidelines on how to provide a reproducible example. I believe what you are looking for can be done with `dplyr` and `join` , `mutate` functions, but we won't be able to help much if you don't provide us with an example.

Answer (score 1):

With base `R`, you could do something like this

```
df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(1:14,2,7))
df2 = as.data.frame(matrix(15:28,2,7))
names(df1)= letters[1:7]
names(df2)= c("a","d",letters[9:12],"b")

m = match(names(df1),names(df2))

newdf = setNames(df1[,which(!is.na(m))]*df2[,na.omit(m)],
                 paste0("mult_",names(df2[,na.omit(m)])))

> newdf
  mult_a mult_b mult_d
1     15     81    119
2     32    112    144
```

Comment: I have tried, but because the number of columns is not different I am getting an error: Error in Ops.data.frame(df1[, which(!is.na(m))], df2[, na.omit(m)]) : 
  ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Answer (score 1):

Find common columns using `intersect`, subset from both the dataframe and multiply

```
common_cols <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df3 <- df1[common_cols] * df2[common_cols]
df3

df3
#   a   c
#1  2 144
#2  6 169
#3 12 196
#4 20 225
#5 30 256
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, c = 12:16)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 2:6, d = 11:15, c = 12:16, e = 1:5)
```

**Update**

Since you have unI think you need to `merge` before multiplying

```
df3 <- merge(df1[common_cols], df2[common_cols], by = "Company")
cbind(df3[1], df3[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)] * df3[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)])
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, getting this error: Error in Ops.data.frame(df1[common_cols], df2[common_cols]) : 
  ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: @VitoK yes, looks like `nrow(df1)` is not same as `nrow(df2)`. Can you update your post with `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)`  ? Also how do you wish to multiply the two dataframes when the number of rows are not equal?

Comment: @RonakShah wouldn't this only work if the same-named columns are in the same position?

Comment: @boski no since we are selecting column by names, they'll be in the same order while multiplying.  Check for `df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, c = 12:16); df2 <- data.frame(c = 2:6, d = 11:15, e = 12:16, a = 1:5)`

Comment: @RonakShah I am thinking the first step should be to transpose df2,  and then it will be only one value per column. I have updated the description.

Comment: @RonakShah For merge I don't want to specify "by"